# Groovy CliBuilder multiple arguments without commas

Tags: groovy

With Groovy's [CliBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html) it's possible to supply multiple arguments as described e.g. here:

- http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/12/groovy-multiple-values-single-option.html

Sample from the above link:

```
def cli = new CliBuilder(  
   usage: 'findClassesInJars.groovy -d <root_directories> -s <strings_to_search_for>',  
   header: '\nAvailable options (use -h for help):\n',  
   footer: '\nInformation provided via above options is used to generate printed string.\n')  
import org.apache.commons.cli.Option  
cli.with  
{  
   h(longOpt: 'help', 'Help', args: 0, required: false)  
   d(longOpt: 'directories', 'Two arguments, separated by a comma', args: Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES, valueSeparator: ',', required: true)  
   s(longOpt: 'strings', 'Strings (class names) to search for in JARs', args: Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES, valueSeparator: ',', required: true)  
}
```

However, this means the script has to be called like this:

```
groovy script.groovy -d folder1,folder2,folder3
```

instead of the more usual (at least in the Unix world):

```
groovy script.groovy -d folder1 -d folder2 -d folder3
```

Is there a way to make it work like in the second example?

Comment: Rather not. Just stupid idea: have You tried setting the separator as `-d`?

Comment: yeah, just leave the valueSeparator off.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, append the letter 's' to the name of the argument. This will, by convention, return an ArrayList that you can iterate through to access all of the values.

```
println "The first directory value: ${option.d}"
println "The directories as a list ${option.ds}"
options.ds.each{ it->
  println "directory: ${it}"
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Would be useful to have an overview of all such conventions

Comment: Refer to the API documentation for CLIBuilder here: [link](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/cli/commons/CliBuilder.html)

Comment: thanks!
For anyone else looking for the exact reference [here's](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/cli/commons/CliBuilder.html#:~:text=Note%20the%20use%20of%20some%20special%20notation.%20By%20adding%20%27s%27%20onto%20an%20option%20that%20may%20appear%20multiple%20times%20and%20has%20an%20argument%20or%20as%20in%20this%20case%20uses%20a%20valueSeparator%20to%20separate%20multiple%20argument%20values%20causes%20the%20list%20of%20associated%20argument%20values%20to%20be%20returned.) a direct link which can be opened in chrome to jump to the mention `'s'`